# Unable to install virtualbox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Though Virtualbox-dkms and headers are alreday installed but it's still giving this error.I even tried reinstalling both dkms and headers but nothing got updated.

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.
     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.34_Ubuntur133883
```

On reconfiguring as suggested by https://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox i got something like:

```
DKMS: install completed.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-01-05 11:38:19 IST; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 23679 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon virtualbox[23679]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon virtualbox[23679]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon virtualbox[23679]:    ...fail!
Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 05 11:38:19 kajoo-weapon systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

Comment: Did you check `dmesg` as suggested?

Comment: yes, it's giving something like:  "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key"

Comment: I reinstalled the virtualbox-dkms by "sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms" and then rebooted the system to login in to "Enroll MOK" to confirm the installation.Now it is working fine.